# Detect an instance my Qt application is already running then the maximizing it

Tags: windows, qt

My question has already been asked here:

[maximizing the already running instance of a single instance app in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234347/maximizing-the-already-running-instance-of-a-single-instance-app-in-qt)

But whatever is proposed here is a library that doesn't seem to exist anymore.

I've seen several applications do this, But I can't figure out how to do this myself.

If my applicaiton is running, I can detect when the user tries to run it again. What I want to do in this situation I would like the existing applicaiton to be maximized.

I assume I need to use windows libraries for this.

But maybe Qt has something for it?

How is this normally done?

Comment: You can try to use QLocalServer/QLocalSocket, or use a "pid" file along with a QFileSystemWatcher: a new application creates the pid file to a predefined location and deletes it when it quits; if a new application starts and finds an existing pid file, it tries to write to it; the existing application, if any, will detect the change and react to it (possibly by writing something else to the file), if the new application doesn't see any change to the file, it means that a previous application probably crashed.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522874/20143744) is not for Qt but probably is going to be very helpful to you. I am not flagging your question as a duplicate though, because, while the method should work for you, a significant portion of work still is required to turn it into C++.

Comment: I found a way to do it, but not using Qt, using simply C++ and Windows Libraries. This works for me as our application is a Windows exclusive application, but I thought maybe Qt had way of doing it in a simple more elegant manner. I will add the code later as I don't have it available right now